# Symbol imported from mathabx conflicts with amsmath

Tags: symbols, amsmath, mathabx

I ran into a problem implementing the solution from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font). It works if `amsmath` is not used.

I tried adding `\let\oldimplies\implies` but it didn't work. It works if a new command is defined, such as `\Implies`, but I'd rather just redefine `\implies`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\implies}{2}{matha}{"D1}

\begin{document}

$A \implies B$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\implies` is indeed defined in `amsmath`; use a different name. If you *really* want to redefine `\implies`, add `\let\implies\relax` before `\DeclareMathSymbol`.

Comment: @simplejack: isn't that what egreg just showed you how to do? (Maybe I don't understand your follow up question: why can't the name of what be changed?) (The command `\let\oldimplies\implies` does not move the definition of `\implies` to a new name; it sets the definition of the command `\oldimplies` to that of `\implies`, creating it if it didn't previously exist or redefining it if it did. The name `\implies` is not touched.)